# The getter 'length' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: length FutureBuilder with List

Tags: flutter, api, rest

I keep getting the error mentioned above during runtime of my flutter app. Basically what I am trying to achieve is to fetch data from an api and display it in a form of a SliverList by using a FutureBuilder.

This was working perfectly fine until I changed my code for the list from FutureBuilder<List> to FutureBuilder<List> to make use of the class EntertainerEvent which has all the fields I need for display from the json file.
How can I resolve this because it seems like the contructor or the application itslef is not picking up the data when I make use of a custom class.

This is the code for the EntertainerEvent class:

```
    class EntertainerEvent {
      final int eventId;
      final int entertainerId;
      final int eventTypeId;
      final int categoryId;
      final String eventName;
      final String description;
      final String imagePoster;
      final String location;
      final DateTime startDate;
      final DateTime endDate;
      final double entreeFee;
    
      const EntertainerEvent({required this.eventId, required this.entertainerId, required this.eventTypeId,
        required this.categoryId, required this.eventName, required this.description, required this.imagePoster,
        required this.location, required this.startDate, required this.endDate, required this.entreeFee});
    
      factory EntertainerEvent.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> event) {
        return EntertainerEvent(
          eventId: event['EventID'],
          entertainerId: event['EntertainerID'],
          eventTypeId: event['EventTypeID'],
          categoryId: event['CategoryID'],
          eventName: event['EventName'],
          description: event['Description'],
          imagePoster: event['ImagePoster'],
          location: event['Location'],
          startDate: event['StartDate'],
          endDate: event['EndDate'],
          entreeFee: event['EntryFee'],
        );
      }
    }
```

Below is the code for fetching data from the api:

```
Future<List<EntertainerEvent>> fetchEvents() async {
    var result = await http.get(Uri.parse(apiUrl));

    if (result.statusCode == 200) {
      var content = result.body;
      var arr = json.decode(content) as List;

      return arr.map((eve) => new EntertainerEvent.fromJson(eve)).toList();
    } else {
      print('Not loaded');
      throw Exception('Unable to fetch data from the Rest API');
    }
  }

  late Future<List<EntertainerEvent>> _fetchEvents;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _fetchEvents = fetchEvents();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<EntertainerEvent>>(
        future: _fetchEvents,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          var childCount = 0;
          if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
            childCount = 1;
          } else {
            childCount = snapshot.data.length;
          }
          return SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                List<EntertainerEvent> someData = snapshot.data;
                print('data here');
               
                //Do some stuff

               }
              },  childCount: childCount),
           );
       });
  }
```

I do not know what exactly is it that I am missing because this code works if I use the type dynamic instead of the custom class EntertainerEvent.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it with `hasData`:

```
if(snapshot.hasData){
return SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
          
                List<EntertainerEvent> someData = snapshot.data;
                print('data here');
               
                //Do some stuff

             
              },  childCount: childCount),
           );}
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your assistance. Unfortunately this is not viable as null might be returned if the body code completes normally. See error below:                                                                         The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type. (Documentation)  Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.

Comment: This is why I added the last return, the loading spinner, outside `if(hasData)`

Comment: Yes, I noticed that but it gives an error 'A RenderViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderPositionedBox.' which is due to the loadSpinner